# is there a way to style the twitter fabric digits user interface

Tags: twitter-fabric

besides changing colors - is there a way to completely customize the look and feel of the twitter fabric digits login?  E.g. custom background image, moving the text boxes up or down, changing sizes of things?

Comment: Is there any way to customize the UI screen of fabric available now?

Comment: not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can fully customise according to your application.

Go through [it](https://github.com/crashlytics/digits-android) once.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I did go through a sample implementation and it didn't let you customize the views outisde of the things I mentioned.

Comment: I had completely customise the UI of Digit according to my help the help if lib i mentioned above.